# How do I create a dataframe with only some rows from another dataframe, with column names?

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I'm working on a shiny R app in which I need to parse csv files. From them, I build a dataframe. Then, I want to extract some rows from this dataframe and put them in another dataframe.

I found a way to do that using rbind, but it's pretty ugly and seems inadequate.

```
function(set){ #set is the data.frame containing the data I want to extract
  newTable <- data.frame(
    name = character(1),
    value = numeric(1),
    columnC = character(1),
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  threshold <- 0

  for (i in 1:nrow(set)){

    value <- calculateValue(set$Value[[i]])) 
    if (value >= threshold){

      name <- set[which(set$Name == "foo")), ]$Name
      columnC <- set[which(set$C == "bar")), ]$C

      v <- c(name, value, columnC)

      newTable <- rbind(newTable, v)
    }
  }
```

If I don't initialize my dataframe values with `character(1)` or `numeric(1)`, I get an error:

> Warning: Error in data.frame: arguments imply differing number of
>   rows: 0, 1   75: stop   74: data.frame

But then it leaves me with an empty row in my dataframe (empty strings for characters and 0s for numerics).

---

Since R is a cool language, I assume there's an easier and more efficient to do this. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Can `calculateValue()` have a vector input? If yes, you can use `subset(set, calculateValue(Value)>=treshold, select=c("Name", "C"))`

Comment: Yes, I guess so

Comment: or `set[calculateValue(set$Value)>=treshold, c("Name", "C")]`

Comment: Can you give an example "set" dataframe and the code for the `calculateValue` function?

Comment: Sure. Set: an example here https://pastebin.com/VfvGZuNr

The function just returns the given value.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than looping through each row, you can either subset

```
function(set, threshold) {
    set[calculateValue(set$Value) >= threshold, c("name", "value", "columnC")]
}
```

Or use `dplyr` to filter rows and select columns to get the subset you want.

```
library(tidyverse)
function(set, threshold) {
    set %>%
    filter(calculateValue(Value) >= threshold) %>%
    select(name, value, columnC)
}
```

Then assign the result to a new variable if you want a new dataframe

```
getValueOverThreshold <- function(set, threshold) {
    set %>%
    filter(calculateValue(Value) >= threshold) %>%
    select(name, value, columnC)
}

newDF <- getValueOverThreshold(set, 0)
```

You might want to check out https://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html